# CancellationToken UnRegister Action

Tags: c#, task, async-await, async-ctp, cancellation-token

I have a token for various tasks and I need to better manage their cancellation, to be notified of a cancellation I can use:

```
token.Register(RegisterMethod);
```

How can I remove this "subscription"?
Is there any way to "UnRegister"?

I thought about doing a workaround with TaskCompletionSource. But I do not know if it would work well. What is the best way to solve this approach?

Comment: will either of these 2 links help you 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/c2f614f6-c96c-4821-84cc-050b21aaee45
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299903/cancellationtokensource-cancelfalse

Comment: it helps but does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[`CancellationToken.Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321790.aspx) returns a [`CancellationTokenRegistration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokenregistration.aspx) instance. If you call [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokenregistration.dispose.aspx) on that instance, your registration will be removed.

Comment: had missed this, thank you. Although it would be nice if this could be done directly on token ..

Answer (score 3):

You can safely dispose the entire CancellationTokenSource. Without worry about unregister callbacks.

Code:
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L552

The Dispose() method of the CancellationTokenSource will call dispose on every registered callback you added into your Token via Token.Register(callBack).

Answer (score -6):

There is no way to really undo a registration.
While the dispose method will remove the callback the token still contains the information that there is a registration:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

basicTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
 for (;;) {
  var z = DateTime.Today.ToString();
 }
}, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

var basicTask2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
 for (;;) {
  var z = DateTime.Today.ToString();
 }
}, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

//var usingThisCodeWillResultInADeadlock = cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => { });
//usingThisCodeWillResultInADeadlock.Dispose();
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
basicTask.Wait();
```

Disabling the comments will result in a deadlock.

Comment: I am not sure what you wanted to show -- your `basicTask2` is unused, your `basicTask` has infinite loop inside, so no matter what you cannot stop it or cancel it, and you wait for that task which (by definition) never ends. Uncommenting those 2 lines does not change a thing.

Comment: You must be joking. Have you misread the question, or have you never looked what CancellationToken.Register returns?